# If date is on sheet 1, then color the column in sheet 1

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have some dates on my sheet2 in excel.

[image]

My question is, how can I give the B2 and C2 cell a color on the sheet1, if the "monday" date match a date on sheet 2 ?

[image]

The weeknumbers is returnes by another sheet with the first date in the year and then =UGE.NR(Året!B1; 2) and then the next column is =B1+1 then next = C1+1 and so on.

Comment: Monday looks like text unless you had the foresight to make it an actual date and format it as *mmmm*. Same goes for 30. Is it a date formatted as *dd* or just the number 30?

Answer (score 0):

Select columns B:C on sheet1 and create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula.

```
=isnumber(match(day($b1), sheet2!$1:$1, 0))
```

Apply a color that suits your purpose and create the CFR.

[image]

Comment: Hi, if I use this, then i'm not getting a color, and have the same dates as in the question =ER.TAL("SAMMENLIGN(DAG(B1), 'Ark2'!B:B, 0)") and I have selected a color.